# How do i get all the bits present on odd positions in binary representation of integers?

Tags: c++, c++17, bit-manipulation, bit

The bits are enumerated from left to right starting from the leftmost set bit i.e. the most significant bit. For example, the binary representation of 77 is 1001101. Bits present on 1st, 3rd, 5th, and 7th positions in the binary representation are 1,0,1,1 respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Python:**

```
int_val = 77
binary_val = bin(int_val)[2:]
odd_pos_data = [ value for index,  value in enumerate(binary_val,1) if index % 2 != 0 ]
print(odd_pos_data)
```

**Result:**

```
['1', '0', '1', '1']
```

**[This is how to do in C++](https://onlinegdb.com/pycliHDri):**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    int num ;
    cout<<"Enter value : \n";
    cin >> num;
    std::string binary = std::bitset<8>(num).to_string(); //to binary
    cout<<"Binary value : \n\n";
    std::cout<<binary<<"\n\n";
    std::cout<<"Odd Index values:\n";
     for (int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++) {
        if(i % 2 != 0){
        cout<< binary[i]<< " ";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: yess ! if you can do it in c++ that would be great ...

Comment: You have used  python tag

Comment: yeah that was a mistake

Comment: @varru15 I have updated my answer for c++, Try it and accept the answer if it helps.